# Debugging errors in VBA classes in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, debugging, error-handling

I have a module with a function similar to this:

**MainModule**

```
Sub Test()
  On Error Resume Next
  Dim O1 As New Class1
  O1.DoSomething
  On Error GoTo 0
End Sub
```

and a few classes similar to this:

**Class1**

```
Sub DoSomething()
  FindStuff

  'create similar objects who perform similar operations and raise similar errors
  Dim O2 As New Class2
  O2.DoSomething
End Sub

Function FindStuff() As Stuff
  'scan the WorkBook, the file system, etc. and organize the members of the object
  If CorruptedFileSystem Then Err.Raise 514, "File system corrupted"
  If CorruptedWorkBook Then Err.Raise 515, "WorkBook corrupted"
  If Found Then Set FindStuff = FoundStuff
End Function
```

If I set the error trapping to `Break in Class Module` then the `On Error Resume Next` will be ignored and every `Err.Raise` will stop the execution inside the class.

If I set the error trapping to `Break on Unhandled Errors` then the `Err.Raise` will stop the execution at the call on the main module, not inside the class.

So in one case I can't execute the code with handled errors, in the other case I can't debug unhandled errors.

The problem becomes unmanageable when the project grows and the main module creates an object that opens a form (which is another object) that creates more objects. Some of the methods handle their own errors and some are designed to abort and raise the error to be managed by the caller.

Is there a way to handle and debug errors in classes?

**EDIT**

Apparently my question wasn't clear enough. I changed the title and I will try with a clearer example.

**Module1**

```
Sub Test1()
  Dim O As New Class1
  O.UnhandledCall
End Sub

Sub Test2()
  On Error Resume Next
  Debug.Print 1 / 0
  Dim O As New Class1
  O.HandledCall
  On Error GoTo 0
End Sub
```

**Class1**

```
Sub UnhandledCall()
  Debug.Print 2 / 0
End Sub

Sub HandledCall()
  Debug.Print 3 / 0
End Sub
```

**Test1**

Set `Error Trapping = Break on Unhandled Errors` and execute `Test1`. The debugger will not stop at the unhandled error `2 / 0`. Instead it will stop at `O.UnhandledCall`, making it impossible to know what line caused the error, what were the local variable values, the stack, etc.

**Test2**

Set `Error Trapping = Break in Class Module` and execute `Test2`. The debugger will not stop at `1 / 0`, good, because the error is handled. But it will stop at `3 / 0` inside the class even if the error is handled inside the caller function, at the same level as `1 / 0`.

**Sad summary**

So with the first setting I can't see where en error is trhown, with the second setting I cant run a macro that cleanly handles errors.

This is obviously an oversimplified example. The real world case I'm dealing with at this moment is a form that creates dozens of objects, some objects check some text files, other objects open drawings on a CAD via COM, other objects talk to a database, etc. If any of the conditions is inconsistent I want to abort the form opening.

As the objects are created, they execute thousands of lines of code, with hundreds of managed errors. When they find something unmanageable in a file, in a drawing or in a database, they defer the error handling to their caller, climbing the stack up to the form that should fail to open and up to the caller that should detect the error and do something about it.

I would expect the debugger to run smoothly through the managed errors and stop when there is an unmanaged error at the offending line. Instead the debugger works as expected in modules, but in classes it either stops at all the error or it never stops, regardless of whether they are managed or not.

For example if I set `Error Trapping = Break in Class Module` all the managed errors will break the execution as in `Test2`, and my debugging session will never end.

While if I set `Error Trapping = Break on Unhandled Errors` then I will never know what triggered the error, because the debugger will climb through all the classes up to the first object and tell me that that's the line that caused the error as in `Test1`.

Comment: Why would you have such detailed error-handling bracketed by such a sweeping `On Error Resume Next`?

Comment: I don't understand your question

Comment: `On Error Resume Next` suppresses errors and lets the code happily continue to run, defeating the purpose of structured error handling. Your top-level caller should have its own `On Error GoTo CleanFail` or something, to handle any error that bubble up to that point in the call stack.

Comment: I agree with you, and I still don't understand your comment. What is the difference between what you say and what I say? Are you talking about the difference between `CleanFail` and `0`? They are just two ways to do the same thing and don't change the point of my question. I could have added some details on how I manage the failure, but that has no relation with the way the debugger behaves with the handled or the unhandled errors.

Comment: There are two different commenters. Consider doing like @Doug Glancy to notify people you've responded. Beyond that, you seen pretty committed to your current way of thinking, so good luck!

Comment: @DougGlancy Thanks for the @ suggestions, but it looks like I can't notify two users. I'm open to suggestions as long as I understand them. I didn't, I tried to guess what the comment was about and I gave an explanation. I still had neither a confirmation nor correction. I changed the post title and added a clearer example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you've noticed, you can't bubble up runtime errors raised in a class module *and* debug on-the-spot just by tweaking the IDE/debugger settings.

There's another way though. Define a project-wide conditional compilation value, say `DEBUG_MODE`:

[image: VBAProject - Propect Properties]

In your class modules' error handlers, use conditional compilation logic to make a programmatic break:

```
Public Function FetchResults(ByVal filter As String) As Collection
    On Error GoTo CleanFail

    Dim results As Collection
    Set results = this.Repository.Where(filter)

CleanExit:
    Set FetchResults = results
    Exit Function

CleanFail:
#If DEBUG_MODE = 1 Then
    Stop
#Else
    Err.Raise Err.Number 'rethrows with same source and description
#End If
    Set results = Nothing
    Resume CleanExit
End Sub
```

---

If you don't mind the VBE popping up on your puzzled users then you could also use `Debug.Assert` statements to break execution when a condition is not met:

```
Public Function FetchResults(ByVal filter As String) As Collection
    On Error GoTo CleanFail

    Dim results As Collection
    Set results = this.Repository.Where(filter)

CleanExit:
    Set FetchResults = results
    Exit Function

CleanFail:
    Debug.Assert Err.Number <> 0 ' will definitely break here
    Set results = Nothing
    Resume CleanExit
End Sub
```

Comment: I am sorry, but my question wasn't about how to write code that manages errors, was about how the debugger manages the error handling. I edited the title of my question and added more detailed examples. Obviously if writing code in a different way helps, I will take that as an answer

Comment: Precisely. You know what causes the error because you handle them in a way that carries that information up to the error handler that handles it. I don't know how else to put it, sorry.

Comment: If you are talking about carrying the information in two strings instead of one like I did in my simplified example, that's a small improvement. I want the debugger to stop at the error and explore the values of all the local variables, be able to try some quick fix, change the next statement and experiment. I want to do with classes what you do during any normal debugging session while working with modules (which are just another kind of classes, but they behave as expected in the debugger)

Comment: Standard modules have completely nothing at all to do with class modules. As Doug said above, *Beyond that, you seen pretty committed to your current way of thinking, so good luck!*

Comment: Again: what new way of thinking are you talking about? I asked a question about the debugger, I received a question in comments and an answer to a question I didn't ask. I understand my original question was unclear, but I think now it is clear what I'm asking. If you have already answered, please tell me where is the answer because I don't see it. If not, please either answer or stop being aggressive without explaining why

Comment: @stenci please see <s>edit</s> rewrite. hope it helps. Didn't mean to come off as aggressive or anything

Comment: The answer is your first row: It is not possible to debug runtime errors thrown in class modules as easily as you can do with standard modules. Then you give generic coding advice, thanks, it is good advice, but doesn't change the behavior of the IDE. I have a comment (just matter of personal taste) about `Debug.Assert`: In VB is useful because it disappears at compilation, but in VBA it is like `Stop` but more difficult to read. I find `If Object Is Nothing Then Stop` more readable than `Debug.Assert Not Object Is Nothing`.